# The command `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` always create a new directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, setup.py

Suppose I have a python package structured like this:

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  setup.py
  bar/
    __init__.py
    bar.pyx
```

and the content of `setup.py` is

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("bar/bar.pyx"),
    include_dirs=[np.get_include()]
)
```

Then I just run

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

because I need the compiled file `bar.so` be placed exactly in `bar/`. But the previous command creates a new directory `foo/bar/` under `bar`, and put `bar.so` there, say,

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  setup.py
  bar/
    __init__.py
    bar.pyx
    foo/
      bar/
        bar.so
```

while what I need is

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  setup.py
  bar/
    __init__.py
    bar.pyx
    bar.so
```

These annoying things happened after I turned `foo` and `bar` to be a package. If I remove `foo/__init__.py` and `bar/__init__.py` then `bar.so` would appear in `foo/`, still not `foo/bar/`. I've read the manual but haven't find a option to handle this problem.

So what should I do if I require `bar.so` to appear in the right place, while keeping the two `__init__.py` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setup.py` shouldn't live inside a package. You'll want to move the package one directory up:

```
foo/
  setup.py
  foo/
    __init__.py
    bar/
      __init__.py
      bar.pyx
```

This is the structure followed by the majority of packages I've come across.

---

As for scikit-learn, which you have used for inspiration:

I certainly don't know exactly what scikit-learn is doing with their multiple `setup.py` files, but I would wager a guess and say that the outer `setup.py` is using (calling, importing) the other `setup.py`s, to hand out the details of the configuration of a subpackage to those individual `setup.py`s. It's just not very visible, because (I think) distutils/setuptools is doing a lot of this importing under the hood.

Thus, the outer setup takes care of the package as a whole, the inner ones take care of the nitty gritty for a subpackage.

But in the end, it's still one big `setup.py` file in the other layer. Trying running

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

on any of the inner `setup.py`s and it will either fail, or do nothing (at least for the two attempts I gave it).

So, those subpackage `setup.py`s could likely be more appropriately seen as `setup_config.py` files.

As an interesting result of this, installing the package will keep those `setup.py` files in their respective subpackages (as well as the one in `sklearn`). Perhaps there's some use for that when one uses the packages, but I guess it's just an artefact of the scikit-learn setup procedure and the inclusion of all `*.py` files.

Comment: Actually I made the directory structure refer to that of `scikit-learn`. But you're right, it should have another layer out of the package. I still have a question though: in `scikit-learn`, except the outer-most `setup.py`, every package has it's own `setup.py` alongside the `__init__.py`, and that's why  I placed my `setup.py` inside a package. How do the inner `setup.py`s work?

Comment: @ludmofans To paraphrase Fermat: I had a comment on that scikit-learn part, but it was too long to fit inside the comment box. I've expanded my answer, which may not fully explain what's going on, but hopefully gives you a good idea of what scikit-learn is doing (note: I don't know any other package so far that's doing things this way).

Comment: Yes you're right, I inspect two `setup.py`s in the `scikit-learn`, and the inner one just set configuration for the sub-package where it is placed. Besides, the outermost `setup.py` use an option called `delegate_options_to_subpackages`, I believe that's the trick.