# Python building cython extension with setup creates subfolder when __init__.py exists

Tags: python, cython, setup.py

I am trying to compile a simple `cython` module using the following `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("verifier_c.pyx"),
)
```

I have the following folder structure:

```
.
c_ext/
  __init__.py
  verifier_c.pyx
  setup.py
```

If I run the following:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

I get an extra `c_ext` subfolder like this:

```
.
c_ext/
  build/
    ...
  c_ext/
    verifier_c.so
  __init__.py
  verifier_c.pyx
  setup.py
```

But if I remove the `__init__.py` file, I get the `verifier_c.so` file in the same folder as `verifier_c.pyx`.

I did not find where this behavior is documented, but I would like to keep `verifier_c.so` in the same folder as `verifier_c.pyx` but without having to delete `__init__.py` each time I run `setup.py`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The `setup.py` is in the wrong folder. Move it up one level and change the argument of `cythonize()` accordingly. Then the `.so` file should show up in the already existing `c_ext/` folder (which is a package if there is a `__init__.py` file present.

Comment: @BlackJack It is not possible to have the `setup.py` and `.pyx` file in the same folder and generate the `.so` in this folder? I would like to totally separate the `c` part from the reste of my app (and thus not put the `setup.py` in the base app).

Comment: I don't know if it's possible somehow but it is just wrong to have the `setup.py` in that spot. It's part of the package the way you organized it.  There is a `c_ext.setup` module this way which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, the `setup.py` should not live inside your package. As far as I know the build_ext commands has no option (apart from `--inplace`) to specify a target path. You can find some documentation [here](http://www.cac.cornell.edu/wiki/index.php?title=Python_Distutils_Tips). Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847561/the-command-python-setup-py-build-ext-inplace-always-create-a-new-directory) deals with a similar topic.

To adapts the required package structure your package would have to look like:

```
c_ext/
    setup.py
    myfile.py
    verifier/
        __init__.py
        verifier_c.pyx
```

You will get an extension that lives in the verifier package:

```
me@machine:~/c_ext/$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace

c_ext/
    setup.py
    myfile.py
    verifier/
        __init__.py
        verifier_c.pyx
        verifier_c.so
```

You can then import verifier_c from the verifier package. For example from `myfile.py` this would look like:

```
from verifier import verifier_c
...
```

You can manage a separate package (and folder) for each Cython extension or create one sub folder that contains all of them. You have to pass the other modules to `cythonize` as well. It can handle a [glob pattern](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), list of glob patterns or a list of `Distutils.Extensions` objects. The latter can be handy to specify cython compiler directives

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension("verifier_c", ["verifier/verifier_c.pyx"]),
    Extension("something_else", ["foobar/something_else.pyx"] compiler_directives={'embedsignature': True}),
    ]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
)
```

I hope this help :)