# Parent module not loaded for Cython library

Tags: python, cython, python-import

I'm trying out Cython, and I wrote a small module to compile. However, when I compile it, the library is written to a subdirectory. Copying that library out of the subdirectory breaks the importing with this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sum_func import sum_func
  File "sum_func.pyx", line 1, in init cython_fail.sum_func
    from itertools import count
SystemError: Parent module 'sum_func' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Why is the import broken, or why is the library being written to a subdirectory in the first place?

I posted the whole project to [GitHub](https://github.com/donkirkby/cython_fail), but the module is pretty simple:

```
# sum_func.pyx
from itertools import count

def sum_func(x):
    n = 0
    for i in count():
        n += i
        if n >= x:
            return -i
```

The setup file is a straight copy from the tutorial:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize("sum_func.pyx"))
```

The driver just calls the library module.

```
from sum_func import sum_func

print(sum_func(10))
print(sum_func(100))
print(sum_func(1000))
```

And the `__init__.py` file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process of trimming out all the unrelated code to post this question, I found the problem: the `__init__.py` file. As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34653047/4794) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31847561/4794), an `__init__.py` file will make Cython compile the library into a subfolder. I didn't find those questions at first, because I was looking for my import error message, not the fact that the library was written to a subfolder.

That's fine, because I didn't really need the `__init__.py` file. I think it was left over from an old version of the project. Deleting it solved the problem.